std::map comparison behave weirdly
Recently, I've been working on a Leetcode problem. In this problem, I tried to create a std::map<string, int> and instead of comparing the string based on alphabetical order, I want to compare them based on their lengths. However, the map ends up having weird entries count.
int maximumLength(string s) {
    int n = (int)s.length();        
    auto comp = [&](const string& s1, const string& s2)  { return (int)s1.length() < (int)s2.length(); };
    map<string, int, decltype(comp)> msi(comp);
    // map<string, int, LengthComparator> msi;
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++)    {
        for (auto j = 1; j < n - i + 1; j++)    {
            string tmp = s.substr(i, j);
            cout << tmp << endl;
            msi[tmp] += 1;
        }
        debug(msi);
    }
    int res = -1;
    for (auto it = rbegin(msi); it != rend(msi); it++)  {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
        // if (it->second >= 3)    {
        //     res = (int)it->first.length();
        //     break;
        // }
    }
    return res;
}

int32_t main() {
    
    string input{"abcdef"};
    cout << maximumLength(input) << endl;

    return 0;
}

The output:
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
abcdef
[msi] = [{("a",1),("ab",1),("abc",1),("abcd",1),("abcde",1),("abcdef",1)}]
b
bc
bcd
bcde
bcdef
[msi] = [{("a",2),("ab",2),("abc",2),("abcd",2),("abcde",2),("abcdef",1)}]
c
cd
cde
cdef
[msi] = [{("a",3),("ab",3),("abc",3),("abcd",3),("abcde",2),("abcdef",1)}]
d
de
def
[msi] = [{("a",4),("ab",4),("abc",4),("abcd",3),("abcde",2),("abcdef",1)}]
e
ef
[msi] = [{("a",5),("ab",5),("abc",4),("abcd",3),("abcde",2),("abcdef",1)}]
f
[msi] = [{("a",6),("ab",5),("abc",4),("abcd",3),("abcde",2),("abcdef",1)}]
abcdef 1
abcde 2
abcd 3
abc 4
ab 5
a 6
-1

There's no way there are 6 a's in my string. So, I wonder where it went wrong. If I remove the comp function it behaves as expected.
I'm using C++23 (Leetcode default). I tried to run with C++14 onward, but same problem.

``` must be on blank lines.

Please describe what problem you are solving, also show an expected output and why you expect it.

@3CxEZiVlQ the expeced behavior was wrongly formatted together with previous ```. Fixed

You're correct -- there are not 6 occurrences of 'a' in your string. However, your comparator cannot distinguish two distinct strings that have the same length. The definition of equality for std::map is !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a) and that is the case for the strings "a" and "b". So, when you add b, it finds a and decides that's already in the map. You seem to want s1.length() < s2.length() || s1.length() == s2.length() && s1 < s2

Side-note: Your auto-capture-by-reference [&] for the lambda is totally unnecessary, and an undesirable habit. You don't need to capture anything in this case, so just use an empty capture group [] when defining the lambda.

Speaking of bad habits,  int32_t main().    The C++ standard specifies that main() returns int.   There is no guarantee that int32_t and int are equivalent.

Hi, thanks @paddy, you're absolutely correct

@Peter duly noted

auto comp = [&](const string& s1, const string& s2)  { return (int)s1.length() < (int)s2.length(); } what monster is that?  Why are you capturing stuff by reference in this stateless lambda?

It is almost always "std::vector", if you put your strings in a vector you can use std::sort to sort your strings with a custom compare operation (e.g. a lambda expression)

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

@paddy you should post that info as an answer instead of a comment.

(here is the essence of my original comment posted as an answer, as requested)
Your custom comparator is not able to distinguish between two strings of the same length, because nowhere do you compare the actual contents of the string.
For ordered containers, the definition of equality is !comp(x, y) && !comp(y, x). In other words: when neither x or y is less than the other, they are deemed equal.
That means every string of the same length will resolve to the same map node, and the key for that node will be whatever string resulted in the node being created. That's why you're seeing a count of 6 for "a" and so on. It's not that you encountered "a" 6 times, but you did encounter 6 strings of length 1.
Here is how you can define an ordering that uses length as the primary criteria, followed by content as the secondary criteria:
auto comp = [](const string& s1, const string& s2) {
    return s1.length() < s2.length()
        || s1.length() == s2.length() && s1 < s2;
};


Your code works as expected -- your comparator compares strings (solely) based on the length, so any two strings of the same length will compare equal, regardless of the string contents.
As a result, your map ends up holding counts of occurences of any string with a given length, where the key stored is just the first string of that length seen.  You have 6 strings of length 1, the first of which is "a", so you get a count of 6 with it.  Similarly, you have 5 strings of length 2, the first of which is "ab".

You answered why the code is not behaving correctly. You should also include a solution to fix the issue.

@RemyLebeau:  The code is working correctly -- it is doing exactly what the OP programmed it to do, with no undefined behavior or other "strangeness".  If this is not what the OP expects (or wants), they need to more clearly state what they expect or want.  The obvious "solution" is to remove the custom comparator, which will make the map comparison work like normal comparison (and they commented that it works).  But since they added the custom compare in the first place, that would not seem to be a useful answer -- it is not at all clear what the OP is trying to do.
